# Mount Samba Share(Linux server) on Linux client machine

Tags: linux, samba

There is Linux server that shares a folder with Windows client but there're also Linux client machines.
I am using KDE and can mount from Dolphin and then do with files and folders as permissions allows:

```
smb://username@server_address/share_folder_name/
```

But i need to mount the way i can access it as a regular path(from console, LibreOffice, mail client etc) and on any DE.

```
mkdir /media/sambaShare
smbclient --user=username -L  //server_address
```

This part works, it shows me Samba server, what folder is shared etc.

```
mount -t cifs //server_address/share_folder_name -o username=username /media/sambaShare
```

And it seems it mounts everything ok. But when i try to access the folder i get:

```
cannot open directory /media/sambaShare/: Permission denied
```

It allows accessing as root but not user. How come via Dolphin i can access as a user but regular way mounting doesn't work? I created the same group on client as in server that can access that folder and as user finally i could went into that folder and see other folders but no further. I can even add files but not edit them.

I'm using Samba Server 3.6.3 on Ubuntu server 12.04
Client machine Kubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to add the `uid=your-user-id` option to your `mount` command. You may also need to add `forceuid` to ignore the user IDs coming from the server (Samba offers a SMB extension to make Unix permissions work as expected; only Unix-like clients request it.) There are similar options for the group ID (`gid` & `forcegid`).

Why? Since normal mounts are system-wide, your local kernel is enforcing permissions. Otherwise, any user on the system could access the share. The default, if you don't pass `uid`/`gid` is the user who ran `mount`—most likely `root`.

See the `mount.cifs` man page for all the CIFS-specific mount options.

Comment: Thank you it worked! Didn't have to go as far as forcegid, passing uid & gid was enough.